# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, opencv

cuando se me abre la ventana para mostrar la camara en vivo me aparece ese error y no se como solucionarlo.
lo que me pone:

```
 File "c:/IA/reconocimientofacial1/capasalidarecfacial.py", line 21, in <module>
    resultado= entrenamientomodeloEigenRecognizer.predict(rostrocapturado)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\eigen_faces.cpp:117: error:
(-2:Unspecified error) This Eigenfaces model is not computed yet. Did you call Eigenfaces::train? in function 'cv::face::Eigenfaces::predict'
```

Comment: 1. Pon un mejor título, que de una idea general del problema, 2. en el cuerpo de la pregunta deben ir todos los detalles del problema y el contexto que existe, decir "me aparece un error", "no me funciona", etc. no es de ayuda. 3. El código va como texto con formato. 4. Lee [ask] y realiza el [tour]

Comment: Por cierto has puesto el mismo nombre a 2 variable (líneas 3 y 4) por lo que la variable toma el último valor asignado, que en tu caso es un string, por eso el error, cambia el nombre de las variables y listo

Comment: entrenamientomodeloEigenRecognizer.read('C:\IA\entrenamientoEigenRecognizer.xml').

Comment: perdon, era asi y me sigue daando el msmo error

Comment: actualiza el código de la pregunta y colócalo como texto (todo)

Comment: Pues esa vaina usa un modelo de aprendizaje que se entrena con datos de prueba y lalalá, y no está entrenado, entonces eso falla porque no está el modelo que se genera al correr un algoritmo de estos sobre datos, que es el que expone esa API con método predict. Fuente: mantengo uno de esos que usa cosas dentro de scikit-learn y expone ese /predict cuando se entrena el modelo.

Comment: anteriormente entrene  el programa y se me creo un archivo que es la ruta en la que pongo en el codigo que mostre antes. perdon soy muy nueva en esto, estoy siguiendo un curso y esta todo igual, pero no se xq me da ese error..